# How to access Security panel on google chrome developer tools with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

The following python code can get console log, but how can I access `Security` tab on Chrome `devTools`? E.g. I want to log about `This page is secure or not (HTTPS) and the TLS certificate status`.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

 yoururl = "test_url"

 caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
 caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
 # driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
 driver = webdriver.Chrome('path_of_chromedriver', desired_capabilities=caps)

 driver.get(yoururl)
 time.sleep(5) # wait for all the data to arrive.
 for log in driver.get_log('browser'):
     print(log)
 driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my solution is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
import json

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {
    'performance': 'ALL',
}
caps['goog:perfLoggingPrefs'] = {
    'enableNetwork': True
}
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
# option.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=option, desired_capabilities=caps)
yoururl = "https://www.google.com.tw/"

driver.get(yoururl)
time.sleep(5)

for log_data in driver.get_log('performance'):
    log_json = json.loads(log_data['message'])
    log = log_json['message']
    if log['method'] == 'Network.responseReceived' and log['params']['response']['url'] == yoururl:
        print(f"securityState={log['params']['response']['securityState']}")
        print(f"securityDetails={log['params']['response']['securityDetails']}")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).